# Writing Clean Url Using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Using on Ubuntu 14.0 version.Checked all the seetings mod_rewrite is on.

```
 AllowOverride All
```

I have a project madeasywebsite.
    In index I have included header and footer which I needed in my whole website.

```
include 'header.php';
    if($pagename=='home/Enquiry'){
       include 'home/Enquiry.php';
    }
```

On getting page name home/Enquiry,it will include home/Enquiry.
Enquiry.php exists in folder home.

```
In header.php I have written this: 
    <a href="index.php?pagename=home/Enquiry">
```

so on getting home/Enquiry it will include Enquiry.php page

I have written htaccess which is in document root

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /madeeasywebsite
    RewriteCond $1 !^(css|js|images|index|home)
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?pagename=([^\s&]+) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ %1?  [R=302,L]
```

Original Url: `<localhost/madeeasywebsite/index.php?pagename=home/Enquiry>`

Url I want:   `<localhost/madeeasywebsite/home/Enquiry>`

I am getting this url,but the problem is it is directly redirecting to
    home/Enquiry.php and not including any header and footer.

I want to include file enquiry.php in index only but in url it should be shown like madeeasywebsite/home/Enquiry.
I am new to htaccess. I have never used it before.
Please help me.I am badly stuck for 7 days.